# Can I post a link to my OpenGL ES 2.0 tutorials for iOS?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, self-promotion

I have started a new series of OpenGL ES 2.0 tutorials for iOS (with code source available under GPL). I would like to know if I can share a link to the tutorials on your community forums. I read the FAQ and it talks about promoting your product and didn't mention anything about tutorials.

The tutorials cover the following subjects:

- Assimp import
- bump mapping
- gpu skinning
- quaternion camera
- skybox
- water reflections

Comment: Stack Overflow is **not** a community forum.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming here that you mean linking to your tutorials as part of an answer to a question asked. You can link to your tutorials, yes. However, there is a big "but".

Your answers here will have to be self-contained. That is, even if you didn't include the link to your tutorial, your answer should still clearly answer the question. This to prevent that your answer will become useless or invalid should the link ever go dead.

If your answer suffices in that regard and you want to provide additional (more detailed) information by linking to your tutorials, you are free to do so.

Even with that in mind, be careful. If every answer you post has a link to a tutorial of yours, and its relevance to the question is not immediately clear, you might run the risk of users thinking you are here to primarily promote yourself. This might result in the occasional flag or even deletion of an answer. (This whole issue has been hotly debated here on Meta on various occasions). So try to give preference to answering the question asked rather than promoting your own material.

Answer (score 2):

You can't/shouldn't add a question which is just a link to your blog. 
You seem genuine (since you took the trouble of going through FAQ n then asking a question here) but this sill can't be done because if this is allowed, soon stackoverflow will become an add portal for technical blogs. 
This is a Q&A site..

Your best bet is, answer OpenGL questions. You can keep track of questions related to specific area/technology/topic using tags.
If you think your blog can help answer a question or help solve a problem, add link to your blog in the answer. If it really is useful, everyone will definitely repost it in other answers.